# PlaceID no longer appearing in Google Places API results

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

Recently I've noticed that Google Geocoding API and Google Places Autocomplete no longer return a result for a critical location - a train station in Vancouver, BC, Canada.

This location, [Burrard Station](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Burrard+Station/@49.2856399,-123.1223818,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x410b7dcecfa3a9f9:0x211c9e02989490bb?hl=en), still appears correctly on Google Maps. It is identified by the placeID, `ChIJ5zwmiYFxhlQRP5j2rGVKYBU`. This placeID returns a result when queried directly using the Google Places API:

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJ5zwmiYFxhlQRP5j2rGVKYBU&key=<redacted>
```

-> http://pastebin.com/A3nL6WKt

However, the placeID appears to be different in the result from above so I'm assuming it is now an alias to a new location. It is no longer returned as a result in Google's Geocoding API:

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=ChIJ5zwmiYFxhlQRP5j2rGVKYBU&key=<redacted>

{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

It is no longer returned as a result in Google's Place Autocomplete APIs using the search term, "Burrard Station".

Previously it was available across all APIs. Can anyone explain why this change may have occurred and what steps to resolution might be? Can a the user owning the location control whether it appears in one API and not another? It's incredibly inconvenient to not be able to select such a key location as a in Google's standard place autocomplete.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a data problem.  This is the response to data issues I see in the issue tracker: "For data related issues, please use the "Send Feedback" link on the bottom right corner of the maps.google.com." 
https://support.google.com/maps/answer/162873

Comment: Thanks, I've reported it as such. We'll see what happens. :)